# How to match exact url parameters passed in in-memory web api in Angular2?

Tags: angular, url, asp.net-web-api, in-memory

I am using a parameter "UnitID" to get data for this particular unit id using following code:

```
this.unitDetailsService.getUnitDetailsbyId(this.activeUnitId)
```

I am using this activeUnitId parameter to construct a url to be used in in-memory service using following code:

```
const url = `${this.unitDetailsUrl}/?unit_id=${unitId}`;
```

I am getting desired results for unit id values like 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.2 etc. 
However, I am getting undesired results for unit id values like 1, 2, 3 etc.
For unit id 1, I am getting all the values which are related to 1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1.
Similarly for unit id 2, result consists 2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.2.
for unit id 3, it is 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4.

I think it is matching to all those values which consists passed unit id rather than matching exact url. Can someone help me to do an exact match?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Where is the matching?

Comment: I mean when I pass unitId = 1, I should get result from api only matching to unitId = 1. For now, I am getting all the results related to 1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1 etc.. i.e whichever unitId contains 1 in it.

Comment: how does your matching algorithm on the api look like? It should be a method similar to `equals(unitId)` instead of `match(unitId)`, because "2.1", "3.1", and "1" are all a match to "1". However, `equals(unitId)` will only return results with the `unitId` you give to the api. Can you provide your api code?

Comment: I am using in-memory web api provided by Angular2. I haven't wrote any code for api. This API is for testing purposes only.

This is the api:
https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Comment: @Jayant Did you get any unit tests for the services calling in-memory-web-api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see. I assume that `${unitId}` will be replaced by e.g. 1. Try adding ^ and $ at the end like this

`${this.unitDetailsUrl}/?unit_id=^${unitId}$`

e.g  `detailedUrl/?unit_id=^1$`

The library use the parameters as though it was a regular expression. Adding ^ means to look at the start of the string, and $ means the end of the string. Passing 1, will then only match 1, not 2.1 or 3.1

Comment: Awesome! This is what exactly I was looking for. Thanks